# How to use System.env() in Flutter pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, circleci

I would like to update `version_code` in pubspec.yaml from the system env variable, like `CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM`.

So in general I would like to have smth like this:

```dart
version: 1.0.0+System.getenv("CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM") ?? 2100000000
```

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: A `.yaml` file is static data.  If you want to customize it programmatically, you will need to write a script that *generates* your desired `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

As someone say in the comment, it's not possible to modify programmatically a YAML file.

But many people have faced the same issues and therefore according to [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/3215) merged PR on the flutter project. You are now able to add a pubspec_overrides.yaml file to your project.

And simply overrides the variable you want :

```
dependency_overrides:
  my_package:
    git:
      url: <my_git_url>
```